# automatic switching uiview after delay

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have two views designed for my app! i would like to know if there is any method, that i could make use of for switching the view automatically after a delay of 10 seconds!

Comment: Yes there is a way to do that. Use a NSTimer or something similiar combined with a simple check on which view that is present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a method that shows your view.

call that method to show after 10 seconds

```
[self performSelector:@selector(showAnotherView) withObject:self afterDelay:10.0];
```